# Javascript, why 'for(v in obj)' and 'obj.hasOwnProperty' can have inconsistent behaviour when the obj is created by different ways?

Tags: javascript

I have three ways to create objects:

```
function createC() {
    function Person(name){
        this.name = name;
        this.getName = function(){  
            return this.name;  
        };
    }
    return new Person("Diego");        
}

function createD() {
    function Person() { };
    Person.prototype.name = "Diego";
    Person.prototype.getName = function () {
        return this.name;
    };
    return new Person();
}

function createE() {
    return Object.create(Object.prototype, {
        name: { value: "Diego" },
        getName: { value: function () { return this.name; } }
    });
}
```

Three objects from each can be used as same, but they have different results when checking their own properties. Here is the function I wrote to check the properties:

```
function checkOwnProperies(obj, name) {
console.log('check object ' + name + '\'s own properties:');
var bIn = false;
for (var v in obj) {
    bIn = true;
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
        console.log('Yes! Found own property: ' + v);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Found a property, but it\'s not own: ' + v);
    }
}
if (!bIn)
    console.log("Didn\'t find any members in " + name + '!');
}
```

The result I got:

```
oC name: Diego
oD name: Diego
oE name: Diego
check object oC's own properties:
Yes! Found own property: name
Yes! Found own property: getName


check object oD's own properties:
Found a property, but it's not own: name
Found a property, but it's not own: getName


check object oE's own properties:
Didn't find any members in oE!
```

The complete snippet: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/homGx

Can someone please explain why the difference?

Comment: The own properties are directly on the object, but  the "not own" properties are inherited. That's how you've set up the objects, so it shouldn't be much of a surprise. Do you have an understanding of prototypal inheritance?

Comment: ...for  the last one, when you use that syntax to create objects, the properties are automatically non-enumerable. They're still on the object, but `for-in` won't enumerate them. You'd need to add `enumerable:true` to the descriptors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it works as expected.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Thanks for your helpful comments. I tried 'name: { emuerable: true, value: "Diego" }' in the 'createE', but it seems 'for' loop still can not iterate the properties.

Comment: @BobL--`emuerable != enumerable`.

Comment: @CrazyTrain please ignore the 'for' loop still not working part of my last comments. It works now. Might be a cache case.